# EWS CreateItem creating all messages as drafts

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use the CreateItem function of Exchange Web Services for Exchange 2010 as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566468%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx to create a message. No matter what I do, the messages always appear in Outlook as drafts. Here is the XML I am sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1"/>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <SavedItemFolderId>
        <t:FolderId ChangeKey="..." Id="..."/>
      </SavedItemFolderId>
      <Items>
        <t:Message>
          <t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">BASE64 ENCODED MESSAGE</t:MimeContent>
          <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
          <t:Subject>THE SUBJECT LINE</t:Subject>
          <t:Sensitivity>Normal</t:Sensitivity>
          <t:Importance>Normal</t:Importance>
          <t:Culture>en-US</t:Culture>
          <t:IsRead>true</t:IsRead>
        </t:Message>
      </Items>
    </CreateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I've tried adding a <t:IsDraft>false</t:IsDraft> to the <t:Message/> but it appears that isn't allowed.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code which then interacts with the Message item..specifically the section dealing with the WebService and the MessageItem

Comment: That's not going to be useful. It's Perl, and I wrote it using LibXML and LWP. I'm not using the C# managed API or any other well known library. The above XML is POSTed, and correctly creates the message. The problem is, when viewing it in Outlook the message appears as a draft.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP Message to EWS to create mail as regular mail, not draft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147045/soap-message-to-ews-to-create-mail-as-regular-mail-not-draft)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` extended property on your `CreateItem` request, [it defaults to `MSGFLAG_UNSENT | MSGFLAG_UNMODIFIED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc839733(v=office.12).aspx) (decimal `10`). In other words, an unread, unmodified draft.

```
The initial values for this property are typically MSGFLAG_UNSENT
and MSGFLAG_UNMODIFIED to indicate a message that has not yet been
sent or changed. When a message is saved for the second time, the
message store provider clears the MSGFLAG_UNMODIFIED flag.
```

If you add the following to your request's `<Message>`, you'll instead be creating a read non-draft:

```
  <t:ExtendedProperty> 
    <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="3591" PropertyType="Integer" /> 
    <t:Value>1</t:Value> 
  </t:ExtendedProperty>
```

(The extended property's `Value` of `1` means `MSGFLAG_READ`.)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game, but we had this and it was due to insufficient storage on the Exchange machine.

Answer (score -1):

Way late, but this came up in a search for me today.

MessageDisposition controls whether it's a draft. You have `<CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly"`, needs to be `<CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy"`

Comment: This will send the message and save a sent-mail copy, not save a non-draft.