# SOAP Message to EWS to create mail as regular mail, not draft

Tags: xml, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In EWS, you can create a draft like this:

```
<tns:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
  <tns:Items>
    <t:Message>
      <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
      <t:Subject>subject</t:Subject>
      <t:Body BodyType="HTML">body</t:Body>
      <t:IsRead>false</t:IsRead>
    </t:Message>
  </tns:Items>
</tns:CreateItem>
```

What do I need to add to create a regular message instead of a draft, as the code above does (using SOAP messages, not the Managed API)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting the extended MessageFlags property did the trick! Has to be done at creation.

```
<tns:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
  <tns:Items>
    <t:Message>
      <t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
      <t:Subject>subject</t:Subject>
      <t:Body BodyType="HTML">body</t:Body>
      <t:IsRead>false</t:IsRead>
      <t:ExtendedProperty> 
        <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="3591" PropertyType="Integer" /> 
        <t:Value>1</t:Value> 
      </t:ExtendedProperty>
    </t:Message>
  </tns:Items>
</tns:CreateItem>
```

Comment: For the benefit of those hitting this issue, extended property `0x0E07` (decimal 3591) is `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS`. Setting it to `1` is setting `MSGFLAG_READ` on the new message, which doesn't seem to matter. But it does! Because if you're setting it to `1`, it means you're **not** setting the bit corresponding to `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` (which happens to be `0x00000008`, and is the default value if your `CreateItem` doesn't specify `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS`). I think.

Comment: See the code example in [How to: Import items by using EWS in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672319(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_importproperties).