# Forwarded email attachment opens in draft mode on Windows, read-only mode on Mac

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in that is using Office.js and EWS. When the user clicks the button on the Home ribbon, the current email item gets forwarded as an attachment to a specific recipient (for testing purposes, an email that I have access to). I've followed the steps listed here to set up the forward-as-attachment functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange#add-an-existing-item-to-a-new-email-by-using-the-mimecontent-and-ews

Everything appears to get forwarded okay, all information is intact (original headers, subject, body, etc). On Outlook 2016 for Mac, I'm able to double-click the attached email and it opens just fine in a read-only type mode. I'm also able to do a "Save As", save it as an .eml file, and view the source in a text editor.

However, on Outlook 2016 for Windows, when I double-click the attached email, it opens in a window titled "Message (HTML) (Read-Only)" , even though it is actually editable (all fields...body, To/CC/Subject, etc.), with the Send button greyed out.

What do I need to do so that on Windows this attached email does not open in this sort of draft mode?

I've included screenshots of what opening the same email attachment looks like on Mac vs. Windows (both Outlook 2016)

[Mac email attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYAU2.png)

[Windows email attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APtvu.png)

Comment: From the attached screenshots, it looks like you are forwarding a read message on Mac and a draft message on Windows. Can you use your Add-in to forward the "reversed" scenarios and reply with the behavior? ("Reversed" meaning draft message on Mac and read message on Windows)

Comment: You could refer to this link:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-msoffice_custom-mso_2016/open-attachment-from-outlook-2016-in-edit-mode/85f69bf0-5806-4bdd-b3a7-c08cd1894f3f
Check the “Enable Protected View for Outlook attachments”

Comment: @AlinaLi I looked into the article...I already have the Protected View enabled. I tried disabling it just to be thorough, but it didn't help

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT So, both of the screenshots are from the same exact email, not two different ones. I have my Outlook account loaded on both my Mac and Windows machines; the screenshots just show what happens when I open that same attachment on the 2 OS's. I am following the process in the docs I linked to in order to "forward as attachment": 1) GetItem (MimeContent of selected email). 2) Create new item 3) Create attachment on new item using MimeContent from step 1. 4) Send new item. We only allow the user to use the add-in on sent emails (emails in their Inbox), never on drafts

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT UPDATE: So, it appears that anytime I open ANY forwarded draft email on Outlook for Mac, it opens in a read mode and not a draft mode. After realizing that, I believe our issue can be simplified to this: 

Following the 4 steps from the documentation to forward an email from the user's inbox as an attachment, through EWS, seems to always treat the attached email as a draft, even though it had technically already been sent/received in the past. **How can we forward an email as an attachment through EWS and make sure it gets sent as a read email and not as a draft?**

Comment: Found a fix! This answer worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147045/soap-message-to-ews-to-create-mail-as-regular-mail-not-draft